# Hibernate ignoring fetch annotation through JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have set up a project using Hibernate through JPA -- i.e. I am defining a persistence unit and working through the EntityManager (e.g. using EntityManager's `find()` method).

I have annotated entity A and B like this:

```
@Entity
class A
{

   @Id
   @Column
   private Integer id;

   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
   @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
   @JoinColumn(name="b_id")
   private B bInstance;


   ...
}

@Entity
class B
{
   @Id
   @Column(name = "b_id")
   private Integer id;

   ...
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "bInstance")
   private Set<A> As = new HashSet<A>();
}
```

Now when I call `findById(Integer id)` to get an A element, I am still getting two select queries instead of a single one with an inner join to the B table.

I know `@Fetch` is a Hibernate annotation so I'm losing JPA's standard, but shouldn't it be working yet?

For the record, this is my `findById` method in my Gneric Dao:

```
public E findById(Class<E> persistentClass, ID primaryKey) {
        validateFindById(persistentClass, primaryKey);

        disableFilter(persistentClass);

        return (E) getEntityManager().find(persistentClass, primaryKey);
    }
```

Comment: Try removing fetch=FetchType.EAGER. Not sure it will make any difference but obviously specifying the mode as JOIN make it implicitly Eager.

Comment: Tried that as well, but it didnt work either :(

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you using. I have tried it with 4.2.7.FINAL and it appears to work as expected.

Comment: i am using version 4.1.8

Comment: Also ok for me in 4.1.8. What are your disableFilter() and validateFindById() methods doing?

Comment: I dont know what a Filter method is...

Comment: disableFilter(persistentClass); validateFindById(persistentClass, primaryKey);

Comment: Oh, right, it disables the filtering of entities by owner. ValidateFindById just checks a valid id was passed.